# How to Clear all apps cache data in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, caching, android-6.0-marshmallow

I know this question has been asked so many times, as I read all the answers but none gave me the complete solution. If Android 6+ is not allowing to clear all apps cache data then how Clean Master app is working. Android has added this permission  in Signature|Prvilege category , then how to get access. Please help.

Comment: Hi! Did you found solution ? Same problem..

Comment: No dude  @researcher

Comment: Same issue!! Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

To clear all apps cached data:

1. Settings
2. Storage & USB
3. Cached data - asks clear cached data?
4. Tap "Ok"

To clear each apps data and cached data

1. Open the Settings menu either through your notification shade (drop-down) or through the Settings app in your app drawer.
2. Navigate down to “Apps”. This may be renamed to something like Applications or Application Manager in OEM skinned versions of Android 6.0.
3. Once in there, click on an application.
4. You’ll now see a list of stuff that gives you information about the app, including Storage, Permissions, Memory Use, and more. These are all clickable items. You’ll want to click on Storage.
5. You should now clearly see the Clear Data and Clear Cache buttons for the application.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the storage section in settings.  Click on the Internal storage.  Look for Cached data and click on that.  Then you get a pop up to clear all the cached data for all apps.  That will clear out a ton of old data.